# redirect_to :action => :index in Rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, testing, rspec

I tried to google for the exact solution for my problem but didn't found any appropriate result, so I'm asking for the solution here.
***Here is the important information***
**Ruby Version** : *ruby 2.2.4p230 (2015-12-16 revision 53155) [x86_64-darwin15]*
**Rails Version** : *Rails 4.2.0*
**Rspec Version** : *3.5.4*
I've a controller which has an action called `clearCart` which basically functions to clearing the `cart session`
**Here is my action**

```
def clearCart
  session[:cart] = nil
  redirect_to :action => :index
end
```

The main aim for the above action is to test `redirect_to :action => :index`.

**Routes for the same action** (if needed)

```
get 'cart/clear' => 'cart#clearCart'
```

**Here is the *Rspec* test to test the same action**

```
describe "GET #clearCart" do
  it "should clear cart" do
    get :clearCart
    subject { get :clearCart }
    subject.should redirect_to :action => :index
    # expect(response).to redirect_to(:index)
    # response.should redirect_to :index
    # before { post :clearCart }
    # render 'index'
    # specify { response.should redirect_to('frontend/cart/index') }
  end
end
```

*(comments are the possible way which I tried to execute the test)*

**Here is my *index action*** (if needed)

```
def index
  render 'frontend/cart/index' ,layout: false
end
```

I usually refer [RELISH](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/2-5/docs/matchers/redirect-to-matcher) for guidance.

Thanks in advance for help.

Comment: That's nothing to do with the question itself, but I would suggest using snake_case for method name and rename it to clear_cart (https://github.com/bbatsov/ruby-style-guide#snake-case-symbols-methods-vars)

Comment: @lightalloy your suggestion will be appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have expect matchers the following code should work

```
describe "GET #clearCart" do
  subject { get :clearCart }
  it { is_expected.to redirect_to(action: :index) }
end
```

In case of shoulda matchers use

```
describe "GET #clearCart" do
  before { get :clearCart }
  it { should redirect_to(action: :index) }
end
```